# Couchdb - how to use effectively with Notepad++

Tags: couchdb, notepad++

I use Notepad++ when coding on Windows, loading and saving to Linux servers via sftp

I'm doing some Couchdb development and Futon is not a great way to write code.

I'm running Couchdb on Linux.

Can anyone suggest an effective mechanism for loading and saving to CouchDB using Notepad++ for Windows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the answer is to use Couchapp which deploys CouchDB code automatically from the file system to a CouchDB database.  That way I can edit the code on the disk.

Answer (score 0):

Are you developing couchapps?

There is a CouchApp Plugin existing for Eclipse. Maybe there is a way to write a plugin for Notepad++ with the same features!?
I am not sure, but when I was testing it, it had no surprising features: deployment (with a configured .couchapprc) and the ability to generate views, etc via secondary mouseclick-menu.

I am working with textmate which has a couchapp plugin that automatically triggers a "couchapp push" uppon document saving.

Also I just learned there is the possibilty to

```
couchapp push --export > appname.json
```

To not push to a database but to a file.

If your intention is to edit Views, then [LoveSeat](https://github.com/kolosy/LoveSeat#readme) could be a solution?

Comment: And I just stumbled over SOCA:https://github.com/quirkey/soca#readme
Soca features autopush.